# Rails repeat block - different values each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, block, yield

I have a block of code that need to be repeated 20 times such as:

```
    <div class="block">
        <%= link_to root_path do %>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <%= image_tag 'image.jpg' %>
         <% end %>
    </div>
```

and only the `<h2>Title</h2>` and `<%= image_tag 'image.jpg' %>` will change.

I was thinking of using an array of all the values and passing them into yields and I need to create a partial for the block and repeat it, but I'm not really sure the best solution for this. So if anyone could point in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I personally would love to see the wrong version, so does the SO community I believe.  Suggest adding your attempt of the solution.

Comment: Can you tell us about the changing values of title and image_tag? Is there any relation between index number and their values?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass your data in by creating a standard Ruby object in your controller - i.e.

```
@images = [
 {
  :title => 'Image One',
  :file => 'image1.jpg'
 },
 {
  :title => 'Image Two',
  :file => 'image2.jpg'
 }
 ...
]
```

Then in your main view:

```
<div class="block">
    <%= link_to root_path do %>
      <%= render "shared/images", :images => @images %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And finally in your partial `shared/_images.html.erb`:

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
 <h2><%= image.title %></h2>
 <%= image_tag image.file %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the collection rendering feature of ROR partials.

Assuming you have an AR model called `Image` with `title` and `image_url` fields,
and `@images` contains array of `Image` objects:

```
<div class="block">
  <%= link_to root_path do %>
    <%= render partial: "meta_info", collection: @images %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

*_meta_info.html.erb*

```
<h2><%= meta_info.title %></h2>
<%= image_tag meta_info.image_url %>
```

**Reference**

Look for *Rendering Collections* section in the page below:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html